# Directly calling a function bound to the exports object

Tags: node.js

I'm reading the `cluster.js` file of the [cluster package](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster) and this part confuses me:

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/plugins').forEach(function(plugin){
  plugin = plugin.replace('.js', '');
  exports.__defineGetter__(plugin, function(){
    return require('./plugins/' + plugin);
  });
});
```

I know that you can bind objects or functions to the `exports` object to expose them to different files, but it seems that it is calling a function already bound to the object. However, I always thought you needed to `require` the file and access functions that way. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is realization of [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) for plugins. Plugin will be loaded only after first access to module property with his name. `__defineGetter__` is the 'syntax sugar' not presented in ECMAScript standard. It binds an object's property to a function to be called when that property is looked up.

Answer (score 0):

If a module sets `exports` to a single function rather than an arbitrary object, then the result of `require` will be a function reference which can be called directly (note that a function is actually a type of object and as such can have properties, which can also be functions).

That's not what's going on here, though. At the time the code you've shown is executed, a function called `__defineGetter__` has already been defined and attached to `exports`. Here it's simply being called as a method of `exports` (presumably because the author didn't feel the need to create a redundant local name for it).

i.e. somewhere along the line there's something like

```
exports.__defineGetter__ = function(propname, getter) {
...
}
```

Since it doesn't have a local name, the only way to call it is through `exports`.

Obviously the purpose of the code here is to allow you to call `cluster.nameOfPlugin.method(...)` without having to manually `require` each plugin, while not requiring all the possible plugins to be preloaded; instead only the ones you actually use get loaded.

Comment: oh, so `__defineGetter__` is not a built in javascript method?

Comment: Nope. Presumably it's a helper function that dynamically generates names for the `get` and `set` operators which *are* built in parts of JavaScript (added in ES5, so not always available in browsers) for defining object properties that invoke accessor functions when referred to.